# How client gets updates from server without frequent ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, server, client, client-server

In my project, there are features like private chat and message notification.
Message notification let as know if there are any new unread messages.

**For achieving that , the idea that came into my mind is**

> Like in a `client` - `server` model , the server should listen for the new requests.
>   Like that , I thought there should be some mechanism to listen to the server for getting information about new messages . Since I know ajax , I used `ajax` request with an interval of 2seconds.

**The ajax requests while checking it in chrome will be something like below .**
[image: Ajax requests under network section in chrome]

> But I thought afterward that, StackOverflow should use the same trick if it was the only idea to do so since they update notifications / vote information asynchronously .

Checking their ajax requests in chrome, it was completely blank.

I need to know how it can be achieved without using frequent ajax requests (which will increase the load on the server).

A simple example with the most efficient technique would be very useful for learning.

Answer (score 11):

This is known as [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), and there are several ways to achieve it:

- Polling (what you are doing - check in regular intervals if there is a message)
- Long-polling (making a request that doesn't get a response until there is a message)
- Streaming (opening a script connection that sends executable JavaScript updates incrementally)
- Websockets (the best option, if supported - all the rest were hacks for what Websockets were finally made to address)

Implementing them is tricky and here are many libraries to choose from that implement them correctly for you (e.g. Socket.IO).

**EDIT:**

> A simple example with the most efficient technique would be very useful for learning.

As I said, you don't want to be implementing those yourself, as they're tricky and full of peril; most good Comet libraries take into account browser's features and choose the best protocol, so that it is transparent for the programmer, making it very easy to develop with this model. For example, check out [Socket.IO tutorials](http://socket.io/get-started/).

Also note that you need a server that is equipped to deal with Comet: e.g. Socket.IO works with Node.JS. They will not work with default Apache, for instance.

Comment: I've had the Chrome developer console open for a while now and I don't see anything new in the network view. Would any of these options do something different that prevents the network traffic from being visible in this manner?

Comment: @Joel From the link provided in the answer _"Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it."_ Because Comet is a reverse ajax. The response is from the server side and not initiated by the browser(client). So I guess the requests won't be shown in the web developer console.

Comment: @Lucky: Not quite how it works. A server cannot initiate a request from the client, without the client contacting the server first.

Comment: OP: If you check Stack Overflow network activity starting from page load, I see `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com`, with Type being `websocket`. Its Time is permanently "Pending". The reason is, it is waiting for the server to say something interesting.

Comment: @Amadan thank you, that clears it up! When I look at the Web Sockets request details, I can actually see the notifications coming through as they happen.

Answer (score 5):

What @Amadan mentioned is perfectly fine but StackOverflow and other StackExchange website mainly use WebSocket for modern browsers (which supports HTML5 and WebSocket).

Open **Developers Console** in Chrome. Go to **Network** Tab, and apply **WS** or **WebSocket** filter and refresh the page. You will see something like below:

[image]